# Send an extra variable in Javascript to another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a Javascript that sends one variable to a PHP file, now I need to add an extra variable to be sent to that PHP file. How do I go about achieving this?

I Have 3 sets of code/pages that work together to send one variable.

Main Page with Javascript:
http://pastie.org/10517825#51-76,120-122

PHP Data process page:
http://pastie.org/10517863

I have a variable called `$team_id`, how do I send `$team_id` into the external PHP file using Javascript?

So if you look at line 9 on the PHP Data process link `$query` variable after `engineer_id` I want to add the statement `AND team_id='$team_id'`. But I don't know how to send `$team_id` from the first page to the second data process PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you just change in ajax call

```
 $.post("updateList.php",{first_variable:value,second_variable:value,third_variable:value,.......}, function(theResponse){
            $("#response").html(theResponse);
            $("#response").slideDown('slow');
            slideout();
        });
```

Comment: Hi, oh that's great. But, how do I retrieve that variable on the second, data process PHP file?

Comment: here you just  
$firstVariable=$_POST['first_variable'];
$secondVariable=$_POST['second_variable'];
$thirdVariable=$_POST['third_variable'];
.......etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you define the variables manually in your javascript code like this:

```
var order = '123456'
var team_id = 'team1'
var engineer_id = 'engineer1'
```

Once this is done, post them as a JSON object:

```
$.post("updateList.php", {order: order, team_id: team_id, engineer_id: engineer_id}, function(theResponse)
```

Then on the PHP side:

```
$order = $_POST['order'];
$team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
$engineer_id = $_POST['engineer_id'];
```

This should make it easier to identify variables too.

Comment: There are many different teams, I can't define them manually as the variable will be different based on the team that the user has selected.